# Where to declare constants for single function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, performance

I have a function in service that is binded to several places (components) in code (path to current displayed img), I'm aware that probably better way would be binding variable and change it when needed, but I would like to know what is faster, better practice:

Declare some constants (I need about 5) inside this function and make these variables declared every change detection cycle runs

**OR**
Declare them as class variables and use them only in that one function (other parts of service don't need them)

Comment: [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: @VLAZ Good article, I'm actually rather curious what is a better practice and the performance is just a side issue.

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ having `const foo = 42` in the body of a method or `this.foo = 42` outside of it is more or less the same in terms of "practice". Both are viable. Depends on how you want to manage this. Mostly a matter of opinion.

Comment: What type of constants are they, just strings?

Comment: @Bergi yes, they are all strings.

Comment: @VLAZ The function is binded so I think there could be big diffrence between declaring few constants few time every second then declare it once on component init.

Comment: You're asking for generic advice. I can tell you there is none. Technically, having variables *in* the function would mean that once the function finishes executing, they should be destroyed. Yet, if that's a something like click handler (fires relatively rarely), it's hardly going to be any drain of resources. The runtime can also optimise on the fly if each execution will use the same constants every time. Yet all this is theoretical and, more importantly, not generically applicable. *Test and profile your code* if you want to find out how *your code* behaves.

Comment: @zywy If they're strings, they're immutable and will be "created" with the same value every time anyway. Just place them inside the function. JS engines optimise strings literals well.